# BlackBerry BIS Push Simple App IllegalStateException: no application instance

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-push

Hi There 
I've tried to implement BB BIS Push notification in my app with the example from the "[Can't register the push server : "no application instance" error](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Can-t-register-the-push-server-quot-no-application-instance-quot/m-p/653799)" thread on the BlackBerry developer forum. I also tried to use [Urban Airship's sample client](https://github.com/urbanairship/bb-push-sample-os5) to workaround this.

Both applications throw the same exception: **IllegalStateException: no application instance** If you look at the developer forum thread, it's very clear, simple and more understandable than Urban's example.

I didn't understand where is the problem? I've tried many things, but I haven't found any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer to my question.

If your cell line doesn't support to BIS service of BlackBerry, you will get this error. I know thats not understandable exception but that is true. I talked with my cell provider and then they opened BIS service for my cell line.

So, it's working now.